# ResultSet How to get String from an object when data is null?

Tags: java, database, oracle, jdbc, resultset

In my Oracle table there are columns with different type.
I want to read all columns as number.

```
String str = resultSet.getString("col1");
```

The problem is that if column in database is defined as number, and value is

> 0.5

the returned string will be

> .5

I can not use any other getter like *getDecimal()* and etc.

If I use:

```
String str = resultSet.getObject("col1").toString();
```

I'll get an exception if the value is null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use

```
String str = String.valueOf(resultSet.getObject("col1"));
```

as a simple workaround to avoid any exceptions. (Not sure why you can't use `resultSet.getDouble("col1")` though.)

Comment: because i want only to print the content, no need to get the right object (I also don't want to check the type of every column (i don't the type of column on design time))

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to see an empty string rather than the literal "null" for a null value (which is what `String.valueOf()`) will produce, you can use:

```
Object value = resultSet.getObject("col1")
String str = value == null ? "" : value.toString();
```

Comment: I need the same result as resultSet.getString("col1");
returns

Comment: I believe toString() will be the same as getString() on a non-string column.